# C# create GS1-128 with Barcodelib

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gs1-128

I use the NuGet package Barcodelib to create the barcode. I wanted to ask if any of you know how to create a GS1 code with this package.
Here is an excerpt of the script where the field txtBarcode.Text is converted

```
            barCode.Alignment = BarcodeLib.AlignmentPositions.CENTER;

        BarcodeLib.TYPE type = BarcodeLib.TYPE.UNSPECIFIED;
        type = BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128;
        try
        {
            if (type != BarcodeLib.TYPE.UNSPECIFIED)
            {
                barCode.IncludeLabel = true;
                barCode.RotateFlipType = (RotateFlipType)Enum.Parse(typeof(RotateFlipType),"Rotate270FlipNone", true);
                Barcode.Image = barCode.Encode(type, txtBarcode.Text, Color.Black, Color.White, nW, nH);
            }
```

can you please give me an example for this? Thanks

Comment: what does this have to do with [tag:visual-studio]?  from the tag: `DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio.`

Comment: also, it already looks like your code does what you are describing it needing to do.  What is the **actual error you are seeing**?

Comment: it's not an error, I just don't understand how to generate a GS1 with the Barcodelib

Comment: a GS1 is CODE128, which is what you are using here.  are you not getting the CODE128 barcode as your output??

Comment: unfortunately GS1-128 is not the same as Code 128 but Code128 is part of GS1-128

Comment: It doesn't appear that GS1-128 is on the supported list for that library: https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib#overview

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, just insert the "È" character

```
string BC = "È" + txtBarcode.Text;
Barcode.Image = barCode.Encode(type, BC, Color.Black, Color.White, nW, nH);
```

thank